# Souls in Terraria

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was playing Terraria in hard mode, then a slime attacked me. I killed it, and it dropped a "Soul of Night." What kind of souls are are there, and what creatures can you get them from?

Answer (score 1):

There are 7 souls, according to the Official Terraria Wiki.

Soul of Flight - Wyvern, Arch Wyvern

Soul of Light - Underground Hallow enemies

Soul of Night - Underground Corruption or Underground Crimson enemies

Soul of Might - The Destroyer

Soul of Sight - The Twins

Soul of Fright - Skeletron Prime

Then on the mobile/console version there is a Soul of Blight which is dropped by Ocram.

All enemies can drop Souls of Night and Souls of Light, depending only on which biome they are killed in.